# Is it possible to have a Map backed by two other maps in Java?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I have two maps in my application, let it be 'users by id' and 'managers by id'. I use them to get user by its id:

```
Map<Id, Person> usersById = new HashMap<Id, Person>();
Map<Id, Person> managersById = new HashMap<Id, Person>();
Person me = usersById.get(myId);
```

Both the entities are persons, so sometime I need to find an arbitrary person by its id. Yes, I can search in one map and then in another one:

```
Person findArbitraryPerson(Id id) {
    Person candidate = usersById.get(myId);
    if (candidate == null) {
      candidate = managersById.get(myId);
    }
    return candidate;
}
```

But, may be, there is a better approach?
Yes, I can create a common map of persons. But I would have to add a new Person instance to that map each time it arrives, and remove it etc. Is it possible to create a kind of a 'backed by two maps' map, to renew it contents automatically? Just as I can create a subMap backed by original map in Collections framework.

Or, may be, there is a better solution?

Comment: what do you mean by "But I would have to add a new Person instance to that map each time it arrives, and remove it etc". Whats the intention here ?

Comment: Why do you have two hashmaps in the first place?

Comment: why can't you use only the user's map? the managers don't have a "user" id?

Comment: Why not make person abstract and have a User class and Manager class that extends Person... then you could have a single HashMap that stores Person which you can put User's and Manager's into (via polymorphism).

Comment: @Puce You're not adding anything useful to this, at all.

Comment: @BrianRoach ? The OP wants to write a "'backed by two maps' map", that was what I was commenting about.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just create a new map, `usersById`, and do `usersById.addAll(usersById);` and `usersById.addAll(managersById)`?

Comment: +1 To what @BenjaminDale posted. Or at the very least you could just add a `boolean` flag to `Person` and an `isManager()` getter. It looks like your ids are just unique to a `Person`

Comment: @BrianRoach : +1.. I think its better to keep a isManager flag rather than having an abstract Person class then Employee and manager Classes extending Person.. Everytime we take an object out, we will have to check whether its a manager or an employee.. keeping isManager prevents these.. Just get the person and check ismanager flag..

Comment: @TheLostMind I did think this when I typed it up. It would then require an instanceof check (imo, not good practice). A boolean flag would be good.

Comment: @Puce Are you completely oblivious to the conversation going on around you, or just don't understand it?

Comment: @BrianRoach I'm just adding another approach. Usually there is not just one solution. We know little about the context.

Comment: Thanks for discussion, guys! I have commented the solutions.

Comment: Why have my comments been removed???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a readonly Map (untested !), which is backed up by any number of other Maps:

```
 private class ReadonlyProxyMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

        private final List<Map<K, V>> maps = new ArrayList<>();

        public void addMap(Map<K, V> map) {
            maps.add(map);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return entrySet().size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            for (Map<K, V> map : maps) {
                if (!map.isEmpty()) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
            for (Map<K, V> map : maps) {
                if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
            for (Map<K, V> map : maps) {
                if (map.containsValue(value)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public V get(Object key) {
            for (Map<K, V> map : maps) {
                if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                    return map.get(key);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public V put(K key, V value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public V remove(Object key) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public Set<K> keySet() {
            Set<K> keySet = new HashSet<>();
            for (Map<K, V> map : maps) {
                keySet.addAll(map.keySet());
            }
            return keySet;
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<V> values() {
            List<V> values = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : entrySet()) {
                values.add(entry.getValue());
            }
            return values;
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
            Set<K> keySet = new HashSet<>();
            Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet = new HashSet<>();
            for (Map<K, V> map : maps) {
                for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    if (!keySet.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                        entrySet.add(entry);
                        keySet.add(entry.getKey());
                    }
                }
            }
            return entrySet;
        }

    }
```

Then you can use:

```
Map<Id, Person> usersById = new HashMap<>();
Map<Id, Person> managersById = new HashMap<>();
ReadonlyProxyMap<Id, Person> allPersons = new ReadonlyProxyMap<>();

...

allPersons.addMap(usersById);
allPersons.addMap(managersById);

...

Person findArbitraryPerson(Id id) {
    return allPersons.get(myId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Puce! Looks like the solution I asked for.. but not sure I want to put this huge scratch of code into my project. Haven't you ever found something like this in some libraries?

Comment: Apache Commons Collections seems to have one: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/CompositeMap.html

Answer (score 3):

An extension (and/or conclusion) to my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304332/is-it-possible-to-have-a-map-backed-by-two-other-maps-in-java#comment32108409_21304332) and @BrianRoach's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304332/is-it-possible-to-have-a-map-backed-by-two-other-maps-in-java#comment32108606_21304332):

```
public abstract class Person {
   // general members and methods shared by managers and users
}

public class User extends Person {
    // User specific members and methods
}

public class Manager extends Person {
   // Manager specific members and methods
}

Map<Id,Person> map = new HashMap<Id, Person>();
map.put(new Id(), new Manager());
map.put(new Id(), new User());
```

OR (if you were so inclined), just have a boolean member on the Person object: `isManager` with appropriate getter/setter.

Comment: Benjamin, good idea, but I would like to have separate maps for users and managers to be able to iterate through all the managers and users. Yes, I can do it in your scratch too, but I have to check class by instanceOf each time..

Comment: Why not just have the boolean flag isManager then? You can have a single map of people, only you can check if they're managers.

Comment: Of course, but this is longer than iterating through the splitted sets of users. My question was, in fact, whether its possible to have BOTH separate and united accesses to 2 groups of items by their id. If map backed by two maps is not available, looks like I have to choose your solution..

Comment: I guess, if you really wanted to, you could wrap two maps in an object and have methods which perform certain actions like getManagerByID(Id id) would select a manager from the managers map.

Answer (score 0):

Surely managers are also people? The better way to do this is to have a map of `Person`s and have `Manager` extend `Person`.

To get a person query the map and return the found `Person`. To get a manager query the map and check if the returned object is an instanceof `Manager` and return null if it is not.

I would wrap the whole `HashMap` into a class of your own and that class should implement `getPerson()`, `getManager()`, `getUser()` with appropriate calls/checks. This also decouples the API from the implementation so in future you can always change it and not have to change any other code.

Comment: >Surely managers are also people? - I am not sure, Tim :) I'd like to keep the ability to iterate through managers and users list separately.

Comment: @KutaBeach For that you would either need a custom iterator (that skips ones of the wrong type) or multiple collections inside your class.